# soft link on windows folder

Tags: windows, ln

I am trying to create soft link of folders on windows. I have cygwin env set in the path so I am able to use ln -s. I am able to create a link but a file is being created rather folder.

I can ls to the file ( which should be folder), and it has all the files but can't cd .
Please refer below image. Please letme what I am missing here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQfIF.png)

Comment: Can you try from a bash prompt instead of Windows command? In Git-bash, `ln -s /c/some/directory` gave me a soft link that worked properly with `cd` and `ls`, and it showed up correctly on in the folder when viewing from Explorer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! On a Windows filesystem, better use Windows tools like [Junction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction).

Comment: I have to create this soft via gitlab runner where I am using cmd as executor. So gitshell won't work here. However, I tried creating using gitshell, it copied the whole folder rather creating soft link.